# Worksheet_change event - change cell value on all sheets when selecting from drop-down list

Tags: vba, excel

I wonder if someone can advise with the following code. It worked well until I added drop-down list into "D4" cell (more precisely, they are merged cells "D4:F4"). These drop-downs in D4 cell are on all sheets of the workbook except for "lists" sheet and hold the same data. These source data are in named table on sheet "lists" and referenced using `INDIRECT` function. What I like to achieve is that "D4" cell value is automatically changed on other sheets if I select an item from drop-down list on any of the sheets.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = wb1.ActiveSheet

If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then GoTo LetsContinue

'Change cell value on all sheets except for sheet "lists"
If Not Intersect(Target, ws1.Range("D4")) Is Nothing Then
    For Each ws In wb1.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "lists" Then
            If Target.Value <> ws.Range(Target.Address).Value Then
            ws.Range(Target.Address).Value = Target.Value
        End If
    End If
    Next ws
Else
    GoTo LetsContinue
End If

LetsContinue:
With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: pleas tell what is not working, what is the problem/error/what have changed??

Comment: hi, I've tried hstay's solution and placed code to Workbook_SheetChange and it is a step forward. Working good when the value is typed manually into "D4" cell, however when I only choose value from drop-down data validation list in D4, nothing changes on other sheets. Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you please be more specific about how the "dropdown-namedtable-Indirect function" relation works for you?

Comment: Try replacing "If Not Intersect(Target," with "If Not Intersect(Target.MergeArea.cells(1))".

Comment: @hstay Yes, sure. On "lists" sheet I have a table named "ExportData" and cell "D4" on all other sheets refers to table's 1st column header "Name". Data validation formula looks as follows: =INDIRECT("ExportData[Name]"). I would need that when I pick a name in "D4" cell, the change will be introduced in other sheets in "D4" cell too. Actually, now I suppose the issue relates to the fact that when selecting from drop-down or deleting the value in "D4", this cell still remains active. Macro is triggered properly only when I manually type the value, press enter and the cell below becomes active.

Comment: @Dan as hard as you are trying to make it work I have been trying to make it fail. Unfortunately and I don't know why, in my case changing the value via drop-down makes all the other sheets "D4" values to change as well. I'll keep investigating on the subject.

Comment: @hstay thank you, after your latest comment I tried the functionality of a macro on a newly created testing file and it works for me too. So, the macro is correct as it is now. I tried to reveal why it does not work in my file and, what is weird, the cause are most probably UDF functions that I have in one of the modules. After deleting these functions all works fine. Do you have any idea why this happens?

Comment: @hstay I have done more research on the internet and found that in case of combination of Worksheet_Change/Workbook_SheetChange event and UDF function in the sheet, the statement Application.Volatile has to be turned to "False" in the function. I tried this in my file and it works like a charm now! Thank you for your time and all your help! Of course, I will mark your answer as helpful too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put your code inside as a Worbook_SheetChange event inside Workbook module instead of using a worksheet event:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Set ws1 = Sh

If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then GoTo LetsContinue

'Change cell value on all sheets except for sheet "lists"
If Not Intersect(Target, ws1.Range("D4")) Is Nothing Then
    For Each ws In wb1.Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Lists" Then
            If Target.Value <> ws.Range(Target.Address).Value Then
                ws.Range(Target.Address).Value = Target.Value
            End If
        End If
    Next ws
Else
    GoTo LetsContinue
End If

LetsContinue:
With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
End Sub
```

Like this your code will work with any sheet of the workbook.